# Liferay WebService for access to Custom Fields

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, liferay

I recently researched on an Android application which uses Liferay 6.1. However, I am stuck with ability to update the custom field's value using Liferay API.

I hooked the custom fields into users_admin portlet user/details.jsp and made public view accessible:

```
<liferay-ui:custom-attribute
    className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"
    classPK="<%= (selUser != null) ? selUser.getUserId() : 0 %>"
    editable="<%= true %>"
    label="<%= true %>"
    name="Course"
/>
```

Also hooked into login portlet create_account.jsp:

```
<div>
        <liferay-ui:custom-attribute
            className="<%= User.class.getName() %>"
            classPK="<%= 0 %>"
            editable="<%= true %>"
            label="<%= true %>"
            name="Course"
        />
</div>
```

Therefore, I need a custom webservice to access these values via http client to post/get value. Any idea where to start looking?
I've tried several webservice tutorials but none offers specific solution on accessing expando value of the custom fields.

Here's roughly what I'm stuck with:

Mobile app -> **Liferay API -> Update custom field info**

Mobile app -> **Liferay API -> Retrieve custom field info**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already mentioned the magic word "Expando", you already know where to look: Check `Expando*Service` in the [docs](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/) (note: Webservices will end in `*Service`, while the 'local' services will end in `*LocalService`.

Using Expandos feels a bit like barebones work with tables: There's an ExpandoTable, ExpandoColumn and ExpandoValue. If you're ok with a sample that uses the LocalService (sorry, no webservice), you might want to check [this little extension](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-podcasting-hook) to Liferay that makes use of the Expando attributes, particularly in [`PodcastingUtil.getEnclosure(...)`](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-podcasting-hook/blob/master/docroot/WEB-INF/src/de/olafkock/liferay/blogs/PodcastingUtil.java).

The codebase should be small enough to get an idea of the basic handling of Expandos, otherwise let me know of open questions. Without looking it up, I expect the remote interface being quite similar to the local interface that I'm using in that project.

Comment: Phew! Thanks for pointing out the existence of that expando service to start with. I think the sample is good enough for me to understand the usage. I'll figure the webservice part soon enough. Thanks again!